# Remove outer label from collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am generating a table from my association checkboxes. Each row shows a checkbox and some additional information.

```
%table
= f.collection_check_boxes :task_ids, @my_collection, :id, :label do |r|
  %tr
    %td= r.label
    %td= r.check_box
    %td= r.object.due_date
```

But this breaks my HTML since the output looks like this:

```
<table>
<span><label for="task_ids_1"> <--- I want to remove this...
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_ids_1">My Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="user[task_ids][]" id="task_ids_1" /></td>
    <td>I'm in.</td>
  </tr>
</label></span> <--- ...and this!
</table>
```

Of course I tried to set `label: false`, but this option has no effect. How can I get rid of the outer label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out by myself almost one year later. There is an option called `boolean_style: :inline` that makes it work.

```
%table
  = f.collection_check_boxes :task_ids, @coll, :id, :label, boolean_style: :inline do |r|
    %tr
      %td= r.label
      %td= r.check_box
      %td= r.object.due_date
```

I found the solution and explanation here https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1266:

> Since you want it to be inline (because you're making it nested by
>   yourself) you need to use boolean_style: :inline config.