# How do I hide the form title that appears inside a legend tag when generating check boxes for an association using simple-form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm using simple-form (Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 5.2.3, simple-form 4.1.0) to generate checkboxes for an association. The form element it generates includes an overall title for the section that defaults to the name of the association (in this case, "Menu item tags") and is inside a  tag. I want to hide it completely, but can't.

I can change the text to "Test" using `label: "Test"`, but label: false doesn't hide it like I'd expect. I've read the docs and done my best to read the source, but I can't make any progress.

Here's the simple-form call:

```rb
    f.association :menu_item_tags, as: :check_boxes
```

And here's the HTML output:

```html
    <fieldset class="form-group check_boxes optional listing_menus_menu_sections_menu_items_menu_item_tags form-group-valid"> 
        <legend class="col-form-label pt-0">Menu item tags</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="listing[menus_attributes][0][menu_sections_attributes][0][menu_items_attributes][0][menu_item_tag_ids][]" value="">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input is-valid check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="listing[menus_attributes][0][menu_sections_attributes][0][menu_items_attributes][0][menu_item_tag_ids][]" id="listing_menus_attributes_0_menu_sections_attributes_0_menu_items_attributes_0_menu_item_tag_ids_1">
            <label class="collection_check_boxes" for="listing_menus_attributes_0_menu_sections_attributes_0_menu_items_attributes_0_menu_item_tag_ids_1">Vegetarian</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

I need to remove the  tag on the second line of the HTML. label: false seems like the obvious convention, but it doesn't work.

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate of [Remove outer label from collection_check_boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975486/remove-outer-label-from-collection-check-boxes). They're using a different function, getting different HTML out, and describing a different problem (that everything is wrapped in a label element). And the solution doesn't fix or affect the behavior I'm describing.

**Edit:** Here's a simplified version of the form in question, in response to a comment below:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @listing do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :menus do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :menu_sections do |f| %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :menu_items do |f| %>
        <%= f.association :menu_item_tags, as: :check_boxes %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate. They're using a different function, getting different HTML out, and describing a different problem (that everything is wrapped in a label element).

Comment: Can u post more about the form. From the document I see they have option `label: false` and `label_html: { class: 'hidden' }`. Are u sure that you use `<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
`

Comment: Sure! I'm adding it as a second edit above.

Answer (score 8):

```
= f.association :menu_item_tags, as: :check_boxes, legend_tag: false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate the legend that is created by simple form with `label: ""`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in css:

```css
form[name="your_form_name"]>fieldset>legend {
    display: none;
}
```

But it's purely cosmetic
;)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

```
label: false
```

should work to hide the generated `<legend>` element.

I tested this and found that this in fact does not work.

The workaround I found to work was:

```
label: ''
```

The `<legend>` element will still be generated but it will be blank.